# SQL Query to determine if value is higher with multiple where clause

Tags: sql

Hi I'm just a beginner with SQL and I am trying to determine if items in a table have a buy price higher than a sell price. The result of the query should show that there are two items in the table with a buy price higher than a sell price, grapes and bread.There can be multiple orders in the table so I'm trying to group them so it also shows each of the orders.

I have been trying to use this SQL query, however I get Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE buy = 'false' AND price > price where buy = 'true' GROUP BY Id
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make any sense to nest `where` clauses like that.  Also, `price > price` will always return `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most lenient interpretation of your requirement is comparing the *highest* buy price against the *lowest* sell price and seeing if the former be larger than the latter.  One way this can be accomplished is by grouping by the `Id` and using aggregation to obtain these high buy and low sell prices.

```
SELECT Id
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN buy = 'true'  THEN price END) >
       MIN(CASE WHEN buy = 'false' THEN price END)
```